# Default values in inheritance classes in python

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I have two classes. Where the Parent class has some default values. 
I would like the Child class to inherit the init() method of the Parent class and also the default values.

However, when I try to change the values of the optional arguments, I can't do it. 
For example, in the code below, I can't change the value of **year_born**.

```
def get_current_age(x):
    return 2017-x
get_age = get_current_age

class Parent():
    def __init__(self,name,last_name, siblings=0, year_born=1900, age=get_age):
        self.name = name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.siblings = siblings
        self.year_born=year_born
        self._get_age = get_age(self.year_born)

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self,name,last_name, siblings=0, year_born=1900, age=get_age):
        super().__init__(name,last_name, siblings=0, year_born=1900, age=get_age)
        self.lives_with_parent= True
        self.stil_in_school= None
```

When I create instances of the Parent class with the default values, the output is ok. When I create a Child instance with a different value for age, it still takes the default value.

```
Dad=Parent('Fyodr','Dosto')
print('Dad is' ,Dad._get_age)

kid = Child('Joseph','Dosto', year_born=2000)
print('Kid is' ,kid._get_age)

Dad is 117
Kid is 117
```

I don't know if you have any other ideas of how to fix this or write it in a better way. 
Many thanks,

Comment: Well, you called `super().__init__(stuff, year_born=1900, ...)`. What did you expect??

Comment: That `super` call is wrong. It should be `super().__init__(name,last_name, siblings, year_born, age)`

Comment: Thank you @pm-2ring
The  __init__(self,name,last_name, siblings=0, year_born=1900, age=get_age)    of the Child should contain the defaults,
but not super().__init___    ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line in Child class:

```
super().__init__(name,last_name, siblings, year_born, age=get_age)
```

Comment: Thank you, that works.  I now see that the defaults should not bee in the call of the super().__init__ function
but only in the definition.  Thanks